# Retrieve Image From clipboard as array

Tags: javascript, shell, activex, clipboard, wsh

I've been brainstorming for a long time now and can seem to come up with a solution for this issue.

Here's the scenario:

Goal: Allow users to take a printscreen (ussing snipping tool, printscreen button, ...) and when they click a button on my html page the clipboard image get's uploaded to a certain location.

Limitations: I **can** only use html, jscript and silverlight. (due to security reasons)

Now I know you can get text from the clipboard with jscript, and you can do the same with silverlight, but I do not seem to have access when it comes to images. WPF supports this (ClipBoard.GetImage) but this is not implemented in Silverligt.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've found a possible workaround, but could use some help in implementing it:

I use javascript to launch paint. If I could now do the following:
- paste the clipboard in paint
- save as .jpg on desktop or whatever
- => i can then upload this file
- delete the file

Answer (score 0):

No, silverlight currently allows only text to be read from the clipboard, you can wait for silverlight 5, but I doubt it will be there and currently it is not possible and there is no workaround.